# get age of git commit using hash

Tags: git, git-hash

If we have a git commit hash:

```
42f35295744738750a665dc846400c8040659d03
```

is there a way to determine/calculate the date it was created without any more info?

Comment: I mean, are you able to run commands? The hash itself doesn't contain any info, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: How about `git show -s --format=%ci 42f35295744738750a665dc846400c8040659d03` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, no.  You can easily extract either of the two time-stamps (author-date and committer-date) but neither one necessarily has anything to do with the *actual* creation date.  For instance:

```
$ GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='1970-1-1 00:00:00' GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='1970-1-1 00:00:00' git commit -m gotcha
[master (root-commit) 30e9626] gotcha
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 foo
$ git log --pretty=fuller | sed 's/@/ /'
commit 30e9626dce78fd41c7ef6fae317e0ed61863f0cd
Author:     Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com>
AuthorDate: Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 -0800
Commit:     Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com>
CommitDate: Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 -0800

    gotcha
```

But, if you are not worried about the computer clock being wildly wrong and/or users deliberately faking their time-stamps, use `%at` or `%ct` or any of the variants of those to extract the author or committer time stamps:

```
$ git log --no-walk --format=%at HEAD
28800
$ git log --no-walk --format=%cd HEAD
Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 -0800
```

See [the **PRETTY FORMATS** section of the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) for details.

Comment: ah I was wondering if it was in there somewhere and could be extracted without looking at the git log

Comment: for example, I might not even know/care which git repo the hash belongs to

Comment: The actual data are in the Git repository database. The hash is just a key; you can't get the data from the key without the database.

Comment: i thought that date/time info was used to create the hash, and could be extracted but probably not then

Comment: The hash is a checksum of the commit contents. To view a commit's contents, use `git cat-file -p`. You'll see that the two timestamps are *part* of the contents. But if you could reverse-engineer the rest of the contents from just the timestamps, the hashes would be poor.